# how to force collection to include attribute value in select?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

This code

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
     ->addAttributeToSelect('username', 'password_hash')
     ->addFieldToFilter('username', 'name')->getSelect()->__toString();
```

gives me:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_username`.`value` AS `username` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_username` ON 
(`at_username`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
(`at_username`.`attribute_id` = '134') 
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_username.value = 'name')
```

how can I include password hash value into collection to get its **select query** ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think below code will work for you

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
     ->addAttributeToSelect('username')
     ->addAttributeToSelect('password_hash')  
     ->addFieldToFilter('username', 'name')->getSelect()->__toString();
 foreach($collection as $customer){
    echo $customer->getPasswordHash();
    echo $customer->getData('password_hash'); 
}
```

Or if you have customerid then use

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$collection->getPasswordHash();
```

Or with name

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_name,'username');
$collection->getPasswordHash();
```

Comment: this gives me hash whe I use `getFirstItem` but how to get select string with this attribute value ?

Comment: @Anonymous check updated answer

Comment: I understand that i can iterate collection and just use `getData`, but to get raw query ? tried `load` on collection but no luck

Comment: @Anonymous check updated answer